# Ffmpeg silent audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a string that outputs 4x mp4.
I would like to add quiet audio to the outputs.
I have tried to insert *anullsrc=cl=mono:sample_rate=48000* but don't really know where to insert it. It gives me an error.

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i test.mxf -filter_complex "[0:v]yadif=1,format=yuv420p,split=4[vid1][vid2][vid3][vid4];[vid1]scale=-2:1080[1080];[vid2]scale=-2:432[432];[vid3]scale=-2:288[288];[vid4]scale=-2:216[216]" -map "[1080]" -map "[432]" -map "[288]" -map "[216]" -map 0:a:0 -c:v h264_nvenc -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*10)" -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -b:v:0 4.5M -b:v:1 1.5M -b:v:2 1.0M -b:v:3 0.5M -c:a aac -b:a 192k -f tee "[select=\'v:0,a\']1080.mp4|[select=\'v:1,a\']432.mp4|[select=\'v:2,a\']288.mp4|[select=\'v:3,a\']216.mp4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add the anullsrc as a lavfi input and then map it.

You then either have to add `-shortest` or add `-t X` where X is the duration of the video.

`ffmpeg -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i test.mxf -f lavfi -i "anullsrc=cl=mono:sample_rate=48000" -filter_complex "[0:v]yadif=1,format=yuv420p,split=4[vid1][vid2][vid3][vid4];[vid1]scale=-2:1080[1080];[vid2]scale=-2:432[432];[vid3]scale=-2:288[288];[vid4]scale=-2:216[216]" -map "[1080]" -map "[432]" -map "[288]" -map "[216]" -map 0:a:0? -map 1:a -c:v h264_nvenc -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*10)" -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -b:v:0 4.5M -b:v:1 1.5M -b:v:2 1.0M -b:v:3 0.5M -c:a aac -b:a 192k -shortest -f tee "[select=\'v:0,a\']1080.mp4|[select=\'v:1,a\']432.mp4|[select=\'v:2,a\']288.mp4|[select=\'v:3,a\']216.mp4"`

Comment: Hi , tried it. No errors but still audio.

Input #1, lavfi, from 'anullsrc=cl=mono:sample_rate=48000':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 384 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 48000 Hz, mono, u8, 384 kb/s

Comment: @ChristianR if you mean you are still hearing audio, and you don't want to, drop this part `-map 0:a:0?`. This is the audio stream from the first input, i.e test.mxf.